# Сортировка двумерного массива

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка

Приветствую.

```
    $result = array();
$i = 0;
$find = $html->find('.class');
foreach($find as $value) {
    $result[$i]['example'] = $value->plaintext;
    $i++;   
}
```

Можно ли сортировать массив $result[$i]['seed'] по убыванию? Просьба подсказать, как это сделать. Перепробовал уже все функции сортировки, сортирует как-то неправильно.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я ж так понимаю, что это [всё та же тема][1], которую вы оставили беспризорной. Давайте не плодить вопросы, а разбираться постепенно. Покажите часть исходного массива.

   [1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/254664/php-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E

Comment: Способ, который использовал я в прошлой теме, сортировал так:

Есть числа: 9, 927, 99, 97. В отсортированном виде будет выглядеть так: 99, 97, 927, 9. Необходимо: 927, 99, 97, 9.

Часть исходного массива через var_dump?

Comment: [0]=> array(1) { ["example"]=> string(8) " 0 " } [1]=> array(1) { ["example"]=> string(8) " 0 " } [2]=> array(1) { ["example"]=> string(8) " 0 " } [3]=> array(1) { ["example"]=> string(8) " 0 " } [4]=> array(1) { ["example"]=> string(8) " 0 " } [5]=> array(1) { ["example"]=> string(8) " 0 " } [6]=> array(1) { ["example"]=> string(8) " 0 " } [7]=> array(1) { ["example"]=> string(8) " 0 " } [8]=> array(1) { ["example"]=> string(9) " 16 " } [9]=> array(1) { ["example"]=> string(9) " 11 " }

Comment: @evansive, вас не смущает то, что мы визуально наблюдаем три символа в значении, а var_dump выдает нам вместо них восемь? Проверьте кодировку - [mb_detect_encoding()][1]

   [1]:http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: Выдает ASCII.

Comment: @evansive, похоже подобрались к сути... А ваши страницы в какой кодировке?

Comment: @Deonis, UTF-8.

Comment: @evansive, Давайте с дпугой стороны зайдем - этот массив упакуйте в json-строку: json_encode($arr);, выведите на экран и посмотрите, есть ли какие-нибудь лишние символы. И проверьте, что страница у вас utf-8 **без BOM**. Возможно, что перед обработкой, надо убрать все управляющие символы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, пробуйте сортиронуть так:

```
function mnsort($a, $b){return strnatcmp($a['seed'],$b['seed']);}
usort($arr, 'mnsort');
```

Если не получиться, то придется искать, что это за невидимые символы в данных, откуда они беруться или чем вызваны. Когда вы копипастите результаты сюда, то эти символы пропадают и выявить их с нашей стороны - не предоставляется возможности.

P.S. Первое на что обратите внимание: как формируются эти данные, откуда беруться, в какой кодировке. Если вы их формируете сами, то повторюсь - убедитесь, что страница у вас в кодировке utf-8 без BOM. Особенно, если эти данные вам приходят в ответе на ajax-запрос с какой-то другой страницы. Обработайте данные на предмет "управляющих последовательностей":

```
trim($text, " \t\n\r\0\x0B");
```

Comment: @Deonis, огромное Вам спасибо, заработало!

 $by = 'seed';
 usort($result, function($a, $b) use($by) {
     return strnatcmp($a[$by], $b[$by]);
 });

А как сортировать по возрастанию?

Comment: Дык поменяйте местами сравниваемые значения.

    return strnatcmp($a[$by], $b[$by]); // туды
    return strnatcmp($b[$by], $a[$by]); // сюды

Comment: @Deonis, еще раз огромное спасибо!

Comment: а зачем там strnatcmp если можно просто

    return (int)$b['seed']-(int)$a['seed'];

? http://ideone.com/uNd66j

Comment: @eicto, вариант с преобразованием типов, был [предложен раньше][1], но он, как я понял, не прокатил (*почему - вопрос другой*).
 
   [1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/254664#254719

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще одна функция сортировки. Сортировка по двум значениям.

```
        function mysortfunc($a, $b) {

            if ($a['itog']>$b['itog']) { return -1; }

            if ($a['itog']<$b['itog']) { return 1; }

            if ($a['itog']==$b['itog']) {
                if ($a['col']==$b['col']) return 0; 
                return ($a['col']>$b['col']) ? -1 : 1; 
            }

        }
        usort($mas, 'mysortfunc');
```